# Builds fails in the gate, but builds fine locally

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

My changeset keeps failing the dev gate build.

Unfortunately TFS build does not give me any clues, this is the only exception I got:

```
Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

I have Google'd it and for those refering to blogs:

- I don't use Fakes
- Server has enough memory

Server has TFS 2012 + update 1

Comment: Have you tried building the project locally using the MSBuild command line?  If that works, try the same thing on the build agent.

Comment: Of course, and when I did this, the same message occurs, no extra details there.. I noticed that when using the UseHostCompilerIfAvailable=false my local MSBUILD goes OK. Applying this param on the build def still returns the MSBUILD error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

This entry in the common property group of one of my test projects was the issue:

```
<CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>true</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>
```

This element must be removed in test projects (MS Test).

I verified it with the other 4 test projects, and they didn't have this entry.

I don't know why this entry is not accepted, but my gate accepts check-ins again ;-)